# Transpose examples table Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

what I want to accomblish is to use a transposed version of my currently used examples table which looks like this:

```
 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | ...
 | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ...
 | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ...
 | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ".." | ...
```

So you can see, we've got much more columns than rows which makes it mendatory to scroll left and right to be able to read the values.
I'd like to put it that way:

```
 | col1  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col2  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col3  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col4  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col5  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col6  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col7  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
 | col8  | ".."| ".."| ".." |
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there any way to solve my problem.
I have to Mention that I'm using Ruby for the step definitions and for the tests:

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you're asking for a way to transpose the table in your text editor?

Comment: @PatrickOscity As far as I understood, the question is whether cucumber is able to read scenario examples from columns rather that from rows. The answer on that is “no, it’s not possible.”

Comment: @mudasobwa, yes, you understood right. Maybe you know some alternative ways how I can do this in elegant form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a transpose method available for cucumber tables, so you can use it in the following way:

```
Given(/^I add the names$/) do |table|
  transposedTable = table.transpose
  @data = transposedTable.rows_hash

  add_names(@data)
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/1.3.17/Cucumber/Ast/Table#transpose-instance_method